# Facebook graph API not showing links/photo's shared on timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am experimenting with the Facebook Graph API on the Facebook developer page to see how it works, and I have something strange. 
I only need read access but I want to retrieve everything posted on my wall except for my own posts. I asked 2 friends to post on my wall to see what it looked like. One of them posted a simple "test" message and I found it by calling:

```
me/feed?fields=id,created_time,from
```

This returns me a JSON object (also) containing the post I just talked about.

The other friend however shared a photo on my wall. I checked a lot of links when using me?metadata=1 to browse through the content but I do not seem to find the right call which shows me the fact that someone shared a photo with me.

Does anyone know:
- why that photo share isn't just appearing in the feed api call?
- where I can find it?
- Did I maybe forgot to add a certain permission to my auth token?

Thanks!